# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I made a basic adding and updating feature to my application. But I have a problem with my map

PRODUCT SLICE:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = [];

const productSlice = createSlice({
  name: "products",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    editProduct: (state, action) => {
      const { id, name, desc, price } = action.payload;
      const existProduct = state.find((product) => product.id === id);
      if (existProduct) {
        existProduct.name = name;
        existProduct.desc = desc;
        existProduct.price = price;
      }
    },
    deleteProduct: (state, action) => {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      const existProduct = state.find((product) => product.id === id);
      if (existProduct) {
        return state.filter((product) => product.id !== id);
      }
    },
  },
});
export const { addProduct, editProduct, deleteProduct } = productSlice.actions;
export default productSlice.reducer;
```

I went on to go add my product slice to my store in my app.

MY PRODUCT PAGE(This is where I add my products page):

```
import { Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { addProduct } from "../../../redux/productSlice";
import Button from "../../views/admin/rtl/featured/Button";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import TextField from "./TextField";

export default function Product() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    desc: "",
    price: "",
    image: "",
  });
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [imageUrls, setImageUrls] = useState([]);

  const onImageChange = (e) => {
    setImages([...e.target.files]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (images.length < 1) return;
    const newImageUrls = [];
    images.forEach((image) => newImageUrls.push(URL.createObjectURL(image)));
    setImageUrls(newImageUrls);
  }, [images]);

  const handleAddProduct = () => {
    setValues({ name: "", desc: "", price: "" });
    dispatch(
      addProduct({
        id: uuidv4(),
        name: values.name,
        desc: values.desc,
        price: values.price,
        image: imageUrls.map((image1) => (
          <img src={image1} alt="" className="image-fluid" />
        )),
      })
    );

    navigate("/rtl/rtl-default");
  };
  return (
    <Box pt={{ base: "130px", md: "80px", xl: "80px" }}>
      <div className="m-auto w-50">
        <TextField
          label="Product Name"
          inputProps={{ type: "text", placeholder: "Tofu..." }}
          value={values.name}
          onChange={(e) => setValues({ ...values, name: e.target.value })}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          label="Product Description"
          inputProps={{ type: "text", placeholder: "Very Delicious..." }}
          value={values.desc}
          onChange={(e) => setValues({ ...values, desc: e.target.value })}
        />
        <br />
        <TextField
          label="Product Price"
          inputProps={{ type: "text", placeholder: "45.." }}
          value={values.price}
          onChange={(e) => setValues({ ...values, price: e.target.value })}
        />
        <br />
        <label className="fs-5 fw-bolder">Product Image</label>
        <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" onChange={onImageChange} />

        <Button onClick={handleAddProduct}>Add Product</Button>
      </div>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

MY PRODUCT LIST PAGE (This is where my added products appear):

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Button from "./Button";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { deleteProduct } from "../../../../../redux/productSlice";

export const ProductList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const products = useSelector((store) => store.products);
  console.log(products);

  const handleRemoveProduct = (id) => {
    dispatch(deleteProduct({ id }));
  };

  const RenderProduct = () =>
    products?.map((product) => (
      <div className="">
        <div className="shadow-lg " key={product.id}>
          <div className="">
            <div>{product.image}</div>
            <h3 className="fw-bold text-center h2">{product.name}</h3>
            <p className="font-semibold text-center mt-0 m-4 p-0">
              {product.desc}
            </p>
            <p className="font-bold text-center fs-5 mt-0 p-0">
              R{product.price}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button
              className="btn text-danger text-center fs-4  d-flex"
              onClick={handleRemoveProduct}
            >
              DELETE
            </button>
            <Link to={`edit-product/${product.id}`}>
              <button className="btn text-success text-center fs-4  d-flex">
                EDIT
              </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
    
  return (
    <div className="w-25">
      <Link to="/addProduct">
        <Button>Add Product</Button>
      </Link>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          {products?.length ? (
            RenderProduct()
          ) : (
            <p className="fw-bold text-warning fs-4">No products yet</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried adding my products then did a console log to see if it was working.

I CONSOLED MY PRODUCTS:

```
 const products = useSelector((store) => store.products);
  console.log(products);
```

MY CONSOLED PRODUCTS:

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{id: '61cf4736-7ff9-4ffc-a475-2a638304c7f7', name: 'hello', desc: 'good', price: '36', image: Array(1)}
1
: 
{id: '8d28429f-4086-4dbe-874f-48318be7dcf9', name: 'Tempeh', desc: 'Its super Delicious', price: '67', image: Array(1)}
2
: 
{id: '067f92e1-c8b7-4749-86a2-e22b2e657e37', name: 'Chillie Oil', desc: 'Its super hot', price: '45', image: Array(1)}
3
: 
{id: '1923699b-46ec-4880-8fdf-43cc906080b3', name: 'Tofu', desc: 'Its super good', price: '67', image: Array(1)}
```

My adding products component page works but its not appearing in my product list page. It only shows it up on my console.

I ALSO GET AN ERROR OF:

```
react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I have seen so many questions related to this error but are not close to my problem.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably You are facing error here <div>{product.image}</div>
Because Image is an array and you are using it as Object key.
try <div>{product.image[0]}</div>

Comment: Hi Kazmi066 , I tried doing that but its still not working

Comment: Please create a sandbox instead adding the code. Although i was able to run your code on my machine and it's just work fine. Why are you storing images as JSX in store when you dispatch `addProduct`? You can just the imagesURL and then in ProductsList, show that image

Comment: Hi  Muhammad Nouman Rafique. You are right. immediately when I removed my image in addProduct() that I dispacthed  and removed my image in product list page it started to show my products on my page but of course whithout the image. Could you please give me a code example on how to add my image. Thank you so much for your help.